# How to display pictures from database?

Tags: php, css, page-template

I am adding all the webpage content to the database. Later on I check the page id and select the corresponding post. There also picture for example:

```
  <img class="componentIcon"  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/bridge_ico.png">  <p class="boxTitle">Bridge</p>
```

This will display the picture from the theme folder, but how to select a picture from the media library in wordpress and display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`wp_get_attachment_image_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) or [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/). You just pass them the ID of the image in the database and the [size](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes) you want.

`wp_get_attachment_image_url()` gives you the URL of the image:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'large' );
// http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/image-1024x1024.jpg
```

While `wp_get_attachment_image()` gives you a full image tag:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'large', false, [ 'class' => 'my-image' ]  );
// <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/image-1024x1024.jpg" class="my-image" etc...
```

If you do want it from your theme folder, then a better method these days is `get_theme_file_uri()`, because it supports being filtered or being replaced by child themes:

```
echo get_theme_file_uri( '/img/bridge_ico.png' );
```

Comment: can I add an img tag to this get_theme_file_uri( '/img/bridge_ico.png' );? I need a css class to style the picture and give coordinates.

Comment: There's no shortcut, you just put that function in the `src` attribute.